# videocapture reads the same frame differently on multiple calls

Tags: java, opencv

I am new to the forum. I have started using Opencv with Java a few weeks ago. In my program I use videocapture to read frames from an avi file. Yesterday I have noticed that, over different runs of my progrem, the n-th frame read from the file is different from the same n-th frame read from the same file, in a previous run. I have confirmed this by subtracting two copies of the same frame, after resetting the video capture to the same frame number. Is this expected, or am I doing something wrong?
Here is the code:

```
/*==========================*/
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    Mat img = new Mat();
    Mat m1 = new Mat();
    Mat m2 = new Mat();

    VideoCapture vc = new VideoCapture(filename);
    vc.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) vc.grab();
    vc.read(img);
    m1 = img.clone();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(m1, m1, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    vc.release();

    vc = new VideoCapture(filename);
    vc.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) vc.grab();
    vc.read(img);
    m2 = img.clone();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(m2, m2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    vc.release();

    Mat m3 = new Mat();
    Core.absdiff(m1, m2, m3);

    if (Core.countNonZero(m3) > 0)System.out.println(Core.sumElems(m3));
}
/*==========================*/
```

In this code I am interested in extracting only the first frame from the video. The "grab" calls are in the two inner loops to make sure to exhaust what it seems to be a frame buffer in the VideoCapture object; the buffer size is 9 in my case, although I am not sure why that is. The outer loop is just to test the overall program multiple times. The output of the System.out is occasionally non-zero, for example 5-6 times over the 100 loop iterations. Instead I would expect it to be always zero, as essentially the program is reading the same first frame twice and, as such, the output of the absdiff should be zero.

Comment: what happens if you remove all the `.grab()` calls? Can you try to use a 2nd VideoCapture? Is your file a video? Does it have some special encoding? If yes, is the first frame a key-frame? Can you provide the input?

Comment: If I replace the .grab with .read, I still have the same issue. 
I am effectively using a 2nd videocapture, as I am releasing the first one and the allocating a new one.
The video I am using is the second one from the list available at:
ftp://motinas.elec.qmul.ac.uk/pub/iLids/
I am not sure whether the first frame is a k-frame, but the same issue is present even if i read the 2nd, 3rd, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have found a solution to my issue, although I am still not sure if that is the proper way to solve this: I have copied the "opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll" file from the Opencv build bin folder to my eclipse project. Now the difference of the two frames is indeed zero, always.

When I followed the guide on the Opencv website on how to integrate Opencv in Eclipse, nowhere it is mentioned to include also this dll.

...now I am wondering how did Opencv manage without that dll in the first place, without giving an error nor exception??? I am sure I do not have any other installations of ffmpeg on my pc. Any thoughts on this?